# Barra de rolagem não desce até o final

Tags: html, css

Tenho um menu lateral que tem posição **fixa**, se diminuo a resolução da tela a barra de rolagem não desce até o final, dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente faço essa barra utilizando a propriedade `overflow` do `css`:

```
overflow: auto;
```

Porém todos os exemplos que vi a posição é setada como `absolute` e não `fixed`.

Como posso fazer essa barra de rolagem descer até o final?

Esse é o `css` completo do menu:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 230px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #263238;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Precisa dar um `padding-bottom: 40px;` nessa resolução

Comment: Não deu certo @Zoom, nada mudou.

Comment: Tá na rede esse sistema aí ?

Comment: Tá na rede local

Comment: Se ficar mais fácil pra você posso fazer um fiddle, mas acho que hoje não da mais tempo rs.

Comment: Como que está sua `meta tag viewport` ?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Taca essa: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: Não deu em nada também.

Comment: Coloca o `padding-bottom` no `UL` não no `#sidebar-wrapper`

Comment: Deve ter algum campo que você possa colocar um `padding: bottom;` ou uma margin!!

Comment: Tenho uma outra `ul` dentro dessa que está com `position:absolute` agora que me toquei, vou tentar colocar nela

Comment: @Zoom era isso mesmo, kk obrigado, coloque uma resposta pra eu marcar como solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina um `padding-bottom` no `ul` que fica dentro do `sidebar-wrapper`.

Provavelmente é o elemento pai do seus LINKs.

Assim a barra de rolagem irá descer mais um tanto para poder ver todos os Links do MENU.